# Overloading for rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue, pass-by-rvalue-reference

Below is a code demonstrating the question:

```
class X {};
X x;
X&& rvalue_ref = std::move(x);
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(rvalue_ref), X&&>::value, "Different types"); //To be sure that type is X&&
void func(X&) {
    cout << "lvalue reference";
}

void func(X&&) {
    cout << "rvalue reference";
}
int main() {
    func(rvalue_ref);
}
```

The output:

```
lvalue reference
```

Could you please explain the reason for that? We have a variable of the type X&& and an overload for this type but this overload isn't called.

Comment: Rvalue references are considered lvalues. You need to `std::move` the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References don't really work like that. Your argument `rvalue_ref`, despite its type, is an *lvalue expression*. You would have to do `std::move` again to make it an rvalue.

Types and value categories are two separate things, and it can be hard to remember that an expression naming an *rvalue reference* typed object is not automatically an rvalue expression.

Consider also:

```
void foo(T&& ref)
{
   bar(ref);             // lvalue arg
   bar(std::move(ref));  // rvalue arg
}
```

This is also mentioned on [cppreference.com's "Value categories" article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression

Comment: But doesn't that break any rules for function overloads resolution? It looks weird that func(T) isn't called for a variable of the type T.

Comment: @beginpluses It is. Nothing's broken here, it's how C++ works. I concede that value categories can be confusing because they're "invisible". I'd rather like to see an IDE that can show you the value category of some expression on mouse-over, but I don't think any such thing exists yet.

Comment: _"for a variable of the type T"_ You should forget about variables and think about _expressions_. The expression you're passing to `ref` in my example is of type T, not of type T&&. That's just how it works. There's no problem with overloading, only with understanding expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly reasonable behaviour - rvalue reference is a lvalue in C++. Which means to get output

```
rvalue reference
```

you have to use `std::move` like that:

```
int main() {
    func(std::move(rvalue_ref));
}
```

This can be especially confusing when passing parameters to functions. For example, to pass argument as rvalue you have to use `std::move`:

```
void foo(bar &&baz) {
    function_taking_rvalue_reference(std::move(baz));// <--- this move is necessary
}
```